# RenderBox was not laid out

Tags: flutter

This is the error I have:

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#416ac NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/srini/AndroidStudioProjects/idealwieght/lib/Input%20Page.dart:21:13
```

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'Gesture detector.dart';

int height = 180;

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

  

         class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
          int height = 180;
    
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('IdealWeightCalculator'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
            body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ResusableDectector(
                  colour: kContainerColor,
                  cardChild: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'HEIGHT',
                        style: KlabelTextStyle,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            height.toString(),
                            style: KlabelTextStyle,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'cm',
                            style: KlabelTextStyle,
                          ),
                           SliderTheme(
                            data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                                activeTrackColor: Color(0xFFff377f),
                                inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFFffffff),
                                thumbColor: Color(0xFFb00203),
                                overlayColor: Color(0xFF4169E1),
                                thumbShape:
                                    RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
                                overlayShape:
                                    RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30.0)),
                            child: Slider(
                              value: height.toDouble(),
                              min: 120.0,
                              max: 220.0,
                              onChanged: (double newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  height = newValue.round();
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),`
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try placing the first `Column` inside your `Expanded` widget, rather than the other way around. I haven't run this code, but it appears you may not even need the first column under `Scaffold`.

Comment: wrap SliderTheme with Expanded

Comment: I solved it myself. For anyone else with the same error just change constent box MaxWidth to 10.0

Answer (score -1):

I solved it myself for anyone else with same question just change constant boxconstraints in box.dart file .Change width to 20.0,height to 30.0

Comment: You can't do this, because you'll need to upgrade Flutter SDK in the future, then your changes will gonna away.